# How do I commit an Account Creation when using EthereumJ

Tags: accounts, ethereumj

I'm currently using EthereumJ-StandaloneBlock and I'm trying to create an account.

```
Account account = ApiServer.jsonRpc.addAccount(aSCreateAccountIncomingVO.getEmail());

   logger.info("ASCreateAccount-jsonRpc.eth_accounts():"+ApiServer.jsonRpc.eth_accounts());


    try {
        logger.info("ASCreateAccount-account:address"+account.getAddress());
        String address = TypeConverter.toJsonHex(account.getAddress());
        servletObject.setJsonObject("balance",account.getBalance());
        servletObject.setJsonObject("address",address);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm able to get the account.

```
{
  "balance": 0,
   "address": "0x82dec192ab6cae33fdd96a668bb3d6e31dd3fe67"
}
```

but when i restart the program, I can no longer retrieve this account.
Is there a step I'm missing out, like setting AutoBlock, create Block or something?